# Using Bing Custom Search API with Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, bing-api

We are planning to use Hosted UI version of Bing Search and have found it only supports query parameter 'q'. This parameter cannot be used with Drupal as it clashes with Drupal standard parameter which is also 'q'.

Is there anyway we can still use Bing Search Hosted UI without changing Drupal parameter 'q'?

Thanks

Comment: To understand more: Why would this clash in PHP? You can do something like this: $result = file_get_contents($url . "?q=" . urlencode($query), false, $context); where $url is your endpoint url provided on customsearch.ai, $query is your user generated query (no need to use _**q**_ here), and $headers = "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key\r\n"; $options = array ('http' => array ('header' => $headers, 'method' => 'GET')); $context = stream_context_create($options). See this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/quickstarts/php for **web search** PHP call.

Comment: Thanks, this did work but had to apply minor changes to work with 'customconfig'. $result = file_get_contents($url . "?q=" . urlencode($query) . "&customconfig=MYCUSTOMCONFIG&responseFilter=Webpages&mkt=en-us&safesearch=Moderate", false, $context);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reiterating the correct answer based on the above comments with @user2574948. Just replace YOUR_QUERY, YOUR_KEY, and YOUR_CUSTOMCONFIG and it works.

```
$endpoint = 'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bingcustomsearch/v7.0/search';
$term = 'YOUR_QUERY';
$headers = "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: YOUR_KEY\r\n";
$options = array ('http' => array (
                      'header' => $headers,
                       'method' => 'GET'));
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url . "?q=" . urlencode($query) . "&customconfig=YOUR_CUSTOMCONFIG&responseFilter=Webpages&mkt=en‌​-us&safesearch=Moder‌​ate", false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Bing search](https://www.drupal.org/project/winlivesearch) module.

It provides a search tab which pulls results from the Bing web service. The search query can be limited to a set of sites, and various advanced search query strings can be used (or appended to all search queries).

Comment: This module uses an old API (v2) and that's why we are lloking at using Bing Search API v7 or Hosted UI.